# unmodifiable collection issue when retainall is used for two key sets in java

Tags: java, dictionary

```
Map<String,String> map=request.getParameterMap();
```

^ is the unmodifiable map.

```
Set s1= map.keySet();
Set s2= map2.keySet();/* another keyset of local map*/
```

Using `s1.retainAll(s2)` throws an exception: `at java.util.collections$unmodifiablecollection.retainall`

Here `request.getParameterMap()` returns an unmodifiable map.. I tried creating a local map. But the issue stil persists.
Suggest some solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not allowed to modify the keyset of an unmodifiable map as the keyset returned is also unmodifiableSet. You can create a local map from the unmodifiableMap and than use retainAll on local map keyset.

```
Map map1 = new HashMap();
map1 = Collections.unmodifiableMap(map1);
Map map2 = new HashMap();
Map map3 = new HashMap(map1);
Set s1 = map1.keySet();
Set s2 = map2.keySet();
Set s3 = map3.keySet();
s3.retainAll(s2);
```

Comment: If all the OP cares about is the set difference, then copying the map first is overkill.

Comment: Sorry, I mean set intersection.

Answer (score 2):

The `Set.retainAll`  method modifies the set it's being called on.  Assuming the `keySet` method of you unmodifiable map is just a view on to the underlying map, it shouldn't allow modifications.  You probably want to create a new (modifiable) set and then remove items from it:

```
Set s1 = new HashSet(map.keySet());
s1.retainAll(s3);
```

Comment: Now am trying to clone the unmodifiable map and use the cloned map's keyset .. now will retainAll work properly?